# Getting data of last hour

Tags: hive

I need a help on creating a query. I have the following table.

```
Name(String) | Capacity(String) | Time(BIGINT)
```

I want to get rows which have `Time` in last hour. How can I do that?

I tried following but didn't work.

```
select * 
from table1 
where Time > (unix_timestamp() - 60*60*1000);
```

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by _"didn't work"_? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. It occurred because unix_timestamp() was given in seconds and I didn't notice that. Changing the code as follows worked.

`select * 
from table1 
where Time > (unix_timestamp()*1000 - 60*60*1000);`

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a function for that .

One way is ,You have to take hour from unix in shell script

```
select * 
from table1 
where Time > ${hiveconf:onehourago};
```

write above code in a file

And call the above file like below in a shell script.

get hourfromunix by using  `date -d "1 hour ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

```
Hive -hiveconf onehourago=$hourfromunix -f filename.hql
```